# Optimizing of DB resources

Tags: performance

I'm pretty excited about Drupal capabilities in general and consider it as probably the most solid free CMF with a really powerful API. One of the things I'm concerned about is the resources it takes. A basic installation with localization generates about 90 database tables (WordPress generates  11). Can this be optimized or, if it cannot be, does it really matter, does it affect performance?

Answer (score 1):

Table count is not an indicator of optimization. It is actually opposite of what someone might think. Good database design breaks data up into multiple related tables that are kept small in field count. Drupal core has a very efficient relational database design compared to WordPress. I have experience with both platforms and your statement highlights what you must realize about Drupal. Drupal really is a content management framework, WordPress is a content management system. They are vastly different in their capabilities.

So to answer your question plainly, no optimization is required. It already is optimized for a relational database.

As always, choose the right tool for the project. Even though I am a Drupal developer I have recommended Wordpress to several clients. Because their needs and requirements could be satisfied with a simple Wordpress site.

Comment: OK... I understand that one large table is probably less efficient than several smaller tables (e.g. because you can cache it more effectively). However, when I review the installations for Drupal and WP I do not see this difference. I guess Drupal comes much more equipped (with custom fields/taxonomy, blocks, etc) than WP and that's why so much DB data is needed. For simple projects when I need just basic things (or I'm ready to PHP custom fields, etc for my needs) what if I turn off some core modules in Drupal to get a lighter installation with a smaller DB? Should investigate it.

Comment: The installation is "light", the total DB after a default installation is only 4.0mb in MySQL - not that big. Again, table count has NOTHING to do with efficiency! Drupal breaks data down into small tables, especially for field data. There is no concept of fields in Wordpress - you have titles and bodies only. You will also find many plugins for Wordpress write data to the file system rather than the database making controlling Wordpress installations in a code repository a nightmare.